# Define $T:\mathbb{Z}_{12}\longrightarrow\mathbb{Z}_{12}$. Then find the number of inner automorphisms.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

**Question** Define $T:\mathbb{Z}_{12}\longrightarrow\mathbb{Z}_{12}$.
Then find the number of inner automorphisms.

[Question Image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Yz1kTrKRjhXPVCU1DKGGohUJ2wkUOujX/view?usp=sharing)

**MY Approach** $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$ is cyclic $\Longrightarrow\mathbb{Z}_{12}$
is abelian $\Longrightarrow$ If $G=\mathbb{Z}_{12}$, then $G=Z\left(G\right)$, Center of G.

We know that $G/Z\left(G\right)$ is isomorphic to $Inn\left(G\right)$.

$|Inn\left(G\right)|=|G/Z\left(G\right)|=\frac{|G|}{Z\left(G\right)}=1$.

**Book mentions answer is $6$**.

Comment: I think there is some major confusion here, since there does not seem to be any mention of $T$ in the actual question.

Comment: @DietrichBurde No brother actually it is a multiple choice question, so typo errors are very often found.

Comment: Are introductions of completely unused objects also common?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I can add a mobile snapshot if you really want.

Comment: Please, don't use mobile snapshots; just write exactly what is written there.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I have written exactly what is written there, this is not very elite book. I study it for the local competitive exams

Comment: If this is exactly as written, then it is not just "not very elite", it is downright garbage.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft 2 minutes and i will show  you the proof

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I have added the book image and and it is not my fault that i can not afford elite books.And i think i should not be downvoted for that

Comment: I agree that it is a terrible book, and that is not your fault. I mentioned how terrible it is because you should probably look for another one (there are plenty of free sources for this material online of much better quality).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your argument is complicated in a needless way, but it is correct: the only inner automorphism of $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$ is the identity.

Note that, since $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$ is a quotient of $\mathbb Z$, which is abelian, $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$ is abelian. On the other hand, an inner automorphism of a group $G$ is a map from $G$ into itself of the type $g\mapsto hgh^{-1}$. But then when $G$ is abelian this map is the identity, since $hgh^{-1}=hh^{-1}g=g$.

Comment: Sir, Please Show the easy way.

Comment: @MohanSharma I've edited my answer. I hope that what I wrote is clear.